# how to set unlink path using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
router.delete("/:userId/:documentId",(req, res, next)=>{

    let ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

    if(!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.documentId))

        res.status(200).json({
            statusCode: 400,                
            message:"Invalid  Types Id."
        });


     Documents.findById({_id:req.params.documentId,user_id:req.params.userId},  function(err, result) {

        if(err) {
        console.log(err);
     }

    filesystem.unlink("uploads/documents/user_id/_id"+result+".md", function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Deleted the  file: " + result +".md");
    }
  });
});
});
```

here i have an error while deleting images ,how set path particular folder 
error: { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink 'D:\officework\server_code\uploads\documents\user_id_id{ _id: 5c05a559c01f4b2eece9d897,
my project Sturucture is officework\server_code\uploads\documents/user_id/id

Comment: I don't think you can have a colon in a file path.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
filesystem.unlink("uploads/documents/user_id/"+result._id+".md", function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Deleted the  file: " + result +".md");
    }
});
```